# onEachFeature not binding Events (click, onmouseover..) in Leaflet with Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet 1.7.1 with Angular 11. I have the next code:

The html of the rendered component looks like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.1/leaflet.css">

 <div id="map" style="height: 100vh;"></div>
```

This is the component itself:

```
@Component({
   selector: "app-root",
   templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
   styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

map: L.Map;
geojson: L.GeoJSON;

ngOnInit() {        

    this.map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);

    L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        attribution: "ATTRIBUTION",
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1
    }).addTo(this.map);


    this.geojson = L.geoJSON(statesData, {style: style, onEachFeature: 
    onEachFeature}).addTo(this.map);                                
    
    }
 }

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
layer.on({
    mouseover: highlightFeature,
    mouseout: resetHighlight,
    click: zoomToFeature
    });
    }


function resetHighlight(e) {
this.geojson.resetStyle(e.target);

}

function zoomToFeature(e) {
this.map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
}

function highlightFeature(e) {
const layer = e.target;

layer.setStyle({
    weight: 5,
    color: "#666",
    dashArray: "",
    fillOpacity: 0.2
});

if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.edge) {
    layer.bringToFront();
 }

 }

function style(feature) {
return {
    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density),
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
 };
 }

function getColor(d) {
return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
       d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
       d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
       d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
       d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
       d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
       d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                  '#FFEDA0';
}
```

So the problem is that whatever I use in **onEachFeature** method for events on layer like

```
 layer.on({
    click: layer.setStyle({fillColor: 'red'}),
    mouseover: layer.setStyle({fillColor: 'blue'}),
    mouseout: layer.setStyle({fillColor: 'green'})     
  });
```

all layers will be filled with color *green*

And if I use this:

```
  layer.on('click', function(e) {
    layer.setStyle({fillColor: 'red'})
  });
```

No click events will be fired, that is, nothing will happen.

I tried putting the code in different Angular lifecycle methods ngOnInit(), ngAfterViewInit(), same behavior happened.

PC: I replaced commercial code with the code from official Leaflet site: https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

**I saw several problems similar to this, but, or they are not answered, or they are not considering Leaflet in Angular version 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the leaflet file was not good referenced.
In my old project, it was referenced in HTML like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.1/leaflet.css">
```

but actually the right way is by doing it through angular.json file:

```
 "styles": [
                "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
                "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

Also, I want to point out to one more thing that was making me a problem with references in Angular TS:

```
 L.geoJSON(statesData, {style: style, onEachFeature: onEachFeature.bind(this)}).addTo(this.map);
```

**.bind(this)** is used, so we can reach in **onEachFeature** method the elements from our component.

For example:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature.bind(this),
        mouseout: resetHighlight.bind(this),
        click: zoomToFeature.bind(this)
    });
}
```

Component property **this.map** would be undefined without **.bind(this)**

```
function zoomToFeature(e) {
    this.map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
}
```

The whole example is implemented here in Angular 11:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mkxfub

This is Leaflet tutorial:

- https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

References for **.bind(this)**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269991/how-to-bind-data-to-layer-on-in-leaflet